# Pip/Easy_install do not install desired package

Tags: python-2.7, module, pip, python-requests

I am new to Python (2.7) but I am trying to run a program that requires the "requests" module. I have installed pip using the get-pip.py script and registered the Python27 and Python27/Scripts paths as environment variables.

When I run "python -m pip install -U pip" it says the package is already up-to-date.

Following installation guides, when I run "pip install requests" I get a new command prompt line. I tried "easy_install requests" and get the same thing. I tried "pip install --verbose requests" and have the same behavior (so much for being verbose!).

I am running on Windows Vista Ultimate, using the command prompt as administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the "python -m pip install -U pip" actually displayed something, on a hunch I tried:

"python -m pip install requests"

This worked! I don't know why any of the installation guides do not say to do this.